# git checkout origin/master doesn't work?

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

I type in `git checkout origin/master` at the command line and at first am giving the following prompt:

```
Deletion of directory 'dirname1/dirname2' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

It fails pretty much every time I try so I wind up hitting n.  Then I get this:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at c2850cd... - change description
```

I do `git branch` after that and here's what I see:

```
* (no branch)
  remote/branchname
  master
```

Why is it doing that?  How do I make a commit to origin/master in light of this?

Comment: You cannot normally make a commit directly to origin/master. You can only create a branch on top of it and push to it.

Comment: What if I want to merge a branch into origin/master and need to resolve a conflict?  In any event, I've committed directly to trunk before - I just don't understand why I'm unable to do so now?

Comment: You merge your local branch (usually `master`) and then push to origin master. And you should try to manually remove the directory in question and then try again to checkout the branch

Comment: You have some large misunderstandings of how git works and what origin/master is.  You should be working on master, not origin/master.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a guess - it looks like there is a directory in your working copy that does not exist in origin/master.  Normally git would just remove that directory when you change branches.  But in this case it cannot for some reason.  There may be a permissions problem: the directory might be owned by a different user, or might be read-only.

Try deleting the directory that git complains about.  You might need to change its permissions or to use `sudo`.  Then you can use the command `git checkout .` to put it back - hopefully with correct permissions this time.  If I'm right, switching branches should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

just the `master` without its prefix:

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score -1):

GitHub remplace master with main so you have to do

```
git checkout main
```